# Better method for using priority queue on custom objects

Tags: java

I have a class `Node` which contains 2 fields, and I built a priority queue for objects of this `Node`, based on the field `len`.

Now there are 2 ways I do this:

1. `PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<Node>(n);//size n queue`
   This method allows for the Comparable Interface to be implemented on class Node, somewhat like this:

   ```
   @Override  
   public int compareTo(Node o){  
       return this.len- o.len;
   }
   ```
2. Other way is:

   `PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<Node>(n, new Node());`

   This allows for the Comparator Interface to be used:

   ```
   @Override  
   public int compareTo(Node node1, Node node2){  
       return node1.len-node2.len;}
   ```

Which of these ways is preferable? Is there any pro/con of using one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the second is somewhat bogus.  The need is for a Comparator, and you give it an object which "happens to implement" a Comparator interface as (I suppose) a sideline to its real purpose.  The Node isn't actually functioning as a Node in this use, it's just a thing with a handy Comparator.

Here's how I see it:

1. If your Nodes have a natural ordering independent of but identical to the order that is needed for this particular priority queue use, then they should implement Comparable, and now you can use it in the priority queue.
2. Otherwise, if there's just a particular order that you need for this particular case, then implement Comparator as a class entirely separate from the Node implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void siftUp(int k, E x) {
    if (comparator != null)
        siftUpUsingComparator(k, x, queue, comparator);
    else
        siftUpComparable(k, x, queue);
}

private static <T> void siftUpComparable(int k, T x, Object[] es) {
    Comparable<? super T> key = (Comparable<? super T>) x;
    while (k > 0) {
        int parent = (k - 1) >>> 1;
        Object e = es[parent];
        if (key.compareTo((T) e) >= 0)
            break;
        es[k] = e;
        k = parent;
    }
    es[k] = key;
}

private static <T> void siftUpUsingComparator(
    int k, T x, Object[] es, Comparator<? super T> cmp) {
    while (k > 0) {
        int parent = (k - 1) >>> 1;
        Object e = es[parent];
        if (cmp.compare(x, (T) e) >= 0)
            break;
        es[k] = e;
        k = parent;
    }
    es[k] = x;
}
```

for second option: you need a NodeComparator which implements Comparator, after do this, these two are the same.
in my opinion, Comparator is a tool for objects comparison, and Comparable express the capability of an object.